# Using bare import via Typescript Compiler Paths opion fails to resolve type on class extends HTMLELement

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, htmlelements

Typescript,

When I import `Component` using a complete path, typescript compilation succeeds:

```js
import { Component } from "../node_modules/@browser-modules/web.component/lib/component.js"

export class Pin extends Component {
}
```

Where `Component` is a class which extends `HTMLElement`:

```js
export class Component extends HTMLElement {
}
```

However, when I import `Component` using bare import, via paths compiler option, the typescript compiler fails to recognize the existence of `HTMLElement` properties on `Pin`.

```js
import { Component } from "@browser-modules/web.component"

export class Pin extends Component {
}
```

Paths in compiler options:

```json
"paths": {
    "@browser-modules/web.component": 
        ["../node_modules/@browser-modules/web.component/lib/component.js"]
}
```

compiler error:

[image: compiler error 1]

To make sure I have specified the correct path, I changed the path to an **invalid** path as follows:

```json
"paths": {
    "@browser-modules/web.component": 
        ["../node_modules/@browser-modules/web.component/lib/component_invalid.js"]
}
```

Now the typescript compiler cannot find the modules and also not the HTMLElement property:

[image: compiler error 2]

It is obvious to me that the compiler should fail when I am using an invalid path.

However, when using the correct path, I would expect the typescript compiler to recognize `Pin` extends `Component` which extends `HTMLElement`

In summary, for some reason, when using bare import, via paths compiler option, typescript compiler fails to recognize properties of `HTMLElement` in extended class `Component`

gitHub [Repo](https://github.com/FlippieCoetser/Buttons) where the complete path is used and compilation succeeds when executing `npm test`

**am I missing something basic here?**

Comment: First of all, you should not need to map to node_modules. Your resolution is off. Try to add `"moduleResolution": "node"` to your tsconfig. Even if this is what you want, why are you mapping to the javascript file? I don't know if this is causing the issue but you should change it anyway. The mappings are only used for typings. You should change it to point to the module where the declarations exists (the .d.ts file without the extension).

Comment: "moduleResolution": "node" works perfectly! Thanks @tscpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion made by @tscpp:

Add "moduleResolution": "node" to typescript compiler options.

Work like a charm! Thanks!